# D3- multiple onclick events

Tags: d3.js

I'm a bit new to D3, javascript, and Stackoverflow and I'm trying to make multiple onclick events workable for a bar chart.  More specifically, I want to make the bars in the chart grow a little taller and then be able to grow even taller after clicking elsewhere. Below is my code thus far.  Eventually I also want to be able to make the bars rearrange as they originally were after they are in ascending order, which I trigger by clicking the first list child. I have tried putting in more on click events.  Duplicating what I put in for the first list child for the second or third child doesn't hurt anything but when I try to make the actual corresponding variable it messes things up and the svg does not even show.  Should I construct my variables in a different way than what I have for the Ascending order?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

svg {
margin-left:25%;
}


rect:hover {
fill:red;
fill-opacity:1.0;
}


</style>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


</head>

<body>

<ul>
<li>Ascending</li>
<li>Grow</li>
<li>Grow More</li>
<li>Back to Normal Size</li>
</ul>

<script>
//Width and height
            var h = 250;
            var nh = 250;
            var w = 500;            
            var barPadding = 5;

var dataset = [
5,10,13,19,21,25,22,18,15,13,11,12,15,20,18,17,16,18,23,25];

var o = d3.scale.linear()
                   .domain([25,0])
                   .range ([.25,.75])                  

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                            .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                            .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
                            .range([0, h - 150]);  //the higher the number subtracted the shorter the bars are

var yScale2 = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
                            .range([0, h - 100]); 

var yScale3 = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
                            .range([0, h - 50]);                            


//Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);


            svg.selectAll("rect")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i);

               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - yScale(d) + 3; //adding a number makes the bar chart go up
               })                         
              //code below is supposed to make bar width dependent on data value.   

            .attr("width", function(d) {return d - 2;   })  //xScale.rangeBand()


               .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d);  

               })                        
               .attr("fill","rgb(0,0,200)") 
               .attr("fill-opacity", function(d) {return o (d)})

               d3.select("li:nth-child(1)")

               .on("click", function() {
                    asCend();
               });


            svg.selectAll("text")
              .data(dataset)
              .enter()
              .append("text")
              .text(function(d) {return d;})                    
              .attr("x", function(d, i) {
              return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
              })
              .attr("y", function(d) {
              return h - yScale(d) 
              })               
              .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
              .attr("font-size", "11px")
              .attr("fill", "red");


            var asCend = function() {

                svg.selectAll("rect")
                   .sort(function(a, b) {
                       return d3.ascending(a, b);
                    })
                   .transition()
                   .duration(1000)
                   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                        return xScale(i);
                   })//;


                   svg.selectAll("text")                   
                   .sort(function(a, b) {                       
                            return d3.ascending(a, b);                      
                    })

                    .transition()
                   .delay(function(d, i) {
                       return i * 50;
                   })
                   .duration(1000)
                   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                        return xScale(i);
                   });


            };          

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple click events, it might be better to use a single click event that behaves conditionally based on the current state of the bars.  You can persist the current state either as classes (.shortbar, .tallbar, etc...) or, potentially, in the datum of each bar.

Comment: Thank you very much, Scott. I may give that a try at this point...my bars are in svg, though, and I am still getting acquainted with how I can manage svg with different classes. But again, thank you.